# Counting 6 letter words containing atleast 4 vowels

Tags: combinatorics

Using the letters of the word EDUCATION , how many words using 6 letters can be made so that every word contains at least 4 vowels?

Comment: Cases: (i) $4$ vowels; (ii) $5$ vowels.

Comment: Seems like casework will definitely be required.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I hadn't seen they where all of size $6$, now it's easy,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice letters are not repeated. When there are $4$ vowels just select those $4$ vowels in $5$ ways and then select the two consonants in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways. After this there are $6!$ ways to arrange the selected  letters.

When there are $5$ vowels there are $4$ ways to select the consonant and then $6!$ ways to arrange the selected letters.

therefore the answer is $6!(5\binom{4}{2}+4)$